# Capacity less than current size while refreshing telerik grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm running into an issue where when I try and reduce the size of a delimited list and then run a postback, I get an error that reads as follows:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: capacity was less than the current size. 
Parameter name: value
```

I call a JavaScript function in one web control which passes the delimited list (which I am fairly comfortable in saying is correctly formed) to another web control, and that web control sets a hidden field on the main form. It then calls a postback on a button which refreshes my Telerik grid.

The hidden field is being set correctly; the NeedDataSource correctly gets that string, and then gets the relevant objects based on that delimited string. Once the refresh finishes however, it throws the error above, and I'm not sure why. I don't have this issue if I increase the length of the string, which implies to me that some sort of metadata isn't getting updated. I'm not sure why this would happen though.

The code below is the relevant snippets of JavaScript -- not sure how useful it is.

```
//WebControl-1
    function passItemListPLtoDL() {
        var idList = null;
        var requestItemPairList = GetSelectedPullListPair();
        LoadMobileDeliveryList(idList, requestItemPairList);
        return false;
    }


//WebControl-2
    function LoadMobileDeliveryList(items, requestItemPairs) {
        if (items != null) {
            setItemIdList(items);   // set the hidden field in Default.aspx.
        }
        if (requestItemPairs != null) {
            setRequestItemPairList(requestItemPairs);   // set the hidden field in Default.aspx.
        }
        RefreshDeliveryList();
    }

    function RefreshDeliveryList() {
        __doPostBack('<%=btnRefreshDelivery.UniqueID %>', '')
    }

//MainForm
    function setRequestItemPairList(list) {
        var obj = document.getElementById("requestItemPairList");
        obj.value = list;
    }
```

I don't think there is anything else really. I can put in the C# code from the codebehind as well, but I'm not sure how relevant it is.

I saw some other cases of this error turning up on Stack, but I wasn't entirely sure how to interpret them. They didn't seem to be from things that I was doing, so I thought I would ask. Thanks for the input!

Cheers

Comment: As a note, I suspect that the 'value' from the error message refers to the value of the obj, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this.

Turns out Virtualization and Paging were causing weird things to happen with the capacity of a grid that I was leaving. If this is turning up for you, I'd suggest checking out your paging settings on Telerik. It's possible the error is happening somewhere you didn't expect.